# Python - How to remove characters from a string?

Tags: python, string, file

I have a file with the following text:

```
with open("file1.txt", "w") as file1:
    file1.write("d:/Python/files/file1.txt Log:Admin1 Password:12345\n"
                "send message saturday january 2018 Stephen")
```

What I need to do is to rewrite words in a new file that don't contain any character. I tried to split it and check every word by using `in`, but it just gives all words. Here's my code:

```
def changes():
    with open("file1.txt", "r") as file1, open("file2.txt", "w") as file2:
        text = file1.read().split()
        for word in text:
            if word not in "?.!/;:":
                file2.write(str(word) + ", ")
```

What is wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by "don't contain any character"? Does that mean letters and not numbers?

Comment: You're checking whether `word` is a substring of `?.!/;:"`. Instead, I think you want to check whether any of those characters appears in `word` (if I've understood what "don't contain any character" means).

Comment: Does your file really contain the python program in the first box, or just the line `send message saturday january 2018 Stephen`? This text does not contain any punctuation (`?.!/;:`). So what is your program supposed to filter out?

Comment: @hoyland yes you're right

Comment: @Renardo yes, it contains both lines and the aim actually is to filter out the first string

Comment: You can check whether any of the characters are in `word` with `any(map(lambda x: x in word, "?.!/;:"))`. (Swap in `all` and/or `x not in word` depending on precisely what the condition you want is.)

Comment: @hoyland thanks man and it really helped me!